# How to show Interstitial ad after 3rd post in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

i am making app with Android Studio using Wordpress as backend and fetching posts via json api .. now i want to implements AdMob interstitial ads in my app but don’t want to show ads for every post because it will violate AdMob's policy . what is want is that interstitial should show when user click RecyclerView's post for 3rd time , how can i implement that ? in short i want to show ads after 3rd click on button..

this is my button to show ad

```
adapter = new PostAdapter( new ArrayList<>(), new BtnClick() {


            @Override
            public void btnClick() {

                Log.e("Inter Button Clicked", "Button CLicked");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a variable `int clickCount=0;` and in `onClickListener` of that button use this logic

```
 if(clickCount<3){
       clickCount++;
    
     }else{
       clickCount=0;
       showInterestialAd();
}
```